# How to get a Wannier function for a tight-binding model numerically?

Tags: python, condensed-matter, mathematical-modeling, solid-state-physics

I have a question about construction of a Wannier function for a tight-binding model. Let's say we consider the tight-binding model of a 1D chain with two atoms (site A and B in a unit cell). In k-space we can write the single-particle Hamiltonian in following way:

\begin{align}
H = \sum_{k} \Psi_{k}^\dagger h(k) \Psi_k~~,~~\tag{1}\\ 
\Psi_k = ( c_{A,k} ~~ c_{B,k}) ~~,~~\tag{2}\\
 h(k)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon(k) & \Delta(k)  \\
\Delta(k)^\dagger & \epsilon(k)
\end{pmatrix}.\tag{3}
\end{align}

By diagonalizing the single-particle Hamiltonian $h(k)$, we get the Bloch wavefunction $| \psi_{nk} \rangle$ for each $k$, where the Bloch wavefunctions are 2-dimensional. To construct the Wannier function, we can think of it as the inverse Fourier function of Bloch waves:
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
| R n \rangle = \frac{V}{(2 \pi)^D} \int d^{D}k ~~ e^{-i k\cdot R} |\psi_{nk} \rangle ,
\end{equation}
where $|R n \rangle$, $n$, and $R$ are is the Wannier function, the band index, and the real space lattice vector respectively.

***My question is how to construct the Wannier function numerically.*** The picture in my mind is that the resulting Wannier function should be centred at the home unit cell. However,  $| \psi_{nk} \rangle$ is a 2D array, it means that the Wannier function that I compute should be a vector rather than a function. So, how can I interpret the elements of the resulting vector after Wannierization? After Wannierization, what things should I plot in order to see the localized function in real space? I appreciate all comments.

This is my rough and trial code for the Wannierization process in python:

````py
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la 

# Suppose I solved the Hamiltonian and get a set of states 
psi_k = np.array([ la.eigh(H(k))[0] for k in k_list ]) #[0] means returns the eigvecs

# Select the lower band ( 1D chain with 2 atoms > 2 bands in k-space) 
low_band = psi_k[:,:,0]

# Wannier function 
def Wannier(psi_k,r_list, k_list):
    WF = 0
    for r in r_list:
        for i in range(len(k_list)):
            WF += np.exp(-j*k*R) * psi_k[i,:,0]
    return WF*len(k_list)**-1 
```
````

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here, and we hope to see much more of you in the future! I've just added equation numbers to your question since, even if you don't need to refer to them in your question, someone *else* might want to refer to "Eq. 3" instead of "the third equation in Ricky Pang's question". Also, if you click the "Cite" button below your question, you can see that all posts on this site have a BibTeX entry so that they can be cited in papers.

Comment: My edits make this question a lot easier to read, and also bump up the question so that it's back to the top of the home page and therefore visible to more people. However there might still be some aspects of your question which are making it hard for it to get an answer: (1) You seem to have given some Python code to do what you want, but what is wrong with it? (2) You haven't told the audience what $V$ is, nor given an example of what $R$ looks like.

Comment: (3) Since $k$ starts out as a discrete index rather than a continuous one, shouldn't we have a sum like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wannier_function#Definition) right than an integral over $k$?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.